# await with .then behavior

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I'm attempting to update a MongoDB collection and store the updated value in the session. However, the value of "user" stored in the session is the "old" value (i.e. the value to be overwritten, not the new value, as desired). I started off like this:

```
const user = await db.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {key1: value1, key2: value2})

if (user) {
    console.log(`User:${user}`);
    req.session.tempUser = user;
    res.redirect(`/routeA`);

} else {
    console.log(`No Users was found`);
    console.log(`Error:${error}`);
    res.redirect(`/routeB`);
}
```

... then figured that the if-else code was most probably running before the DB had completed its update, which seemed like a reasonable explanation for why I was getting the old value of "user". Then I wrapped the if-else code inside a .then and .catch like this:

```
await db.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {key1: value1, key2: value2})
    
    .then ((user) => {
        console.log(`User:${user}`);
        req.session.tempUser = user;
        return res.redirect(`/routeA`);
    })
    

    .catch ((error) => {
        console.log(`No User was found`);
        console.log(`Error:${error}`);
        return res.redirect(`/routeB`);
    });
```

... believing that the code inside the .then would not execute until the DB had completed its operation. However, I'm getting the same result, i.e. the value of user in the session is the old value of user and not the updated (new) value.

Is the code inside the .then waiting for the DB to complete its operation before executing? Perhaps it is, and the behavior I'm experiencing is the expected behavior for Mongoose? (i.e. "user" is always the current value not the updated value, following a "findByIdAndUpdate").

Comment: I think you may have missed the whole point of `await`. Yes, the effect is the same: the `await` mechanism is based on the Promise mechanism. Something else is causing you to get a different object you expect from the database.

Comment: From [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate)... _"[options.new=false] «Boolean» if true, return the modified document rather than the original"_

Comment: @Pointy, thank you. For sure I'm missing something because I don't yet have a full and proper grasp, and I suspect that my terminology is off somewhat, also. Is it a correct statement to say "Once the promise has been resolved, the code in the .then is executed"? ... is that the wrong way to think about it?

Comment: @TimH yes, the function passed to `.then()` is called after the Promise is resolved. And with `await`, the code after the `await` is "put on hold" until the Promise is resolved. It's like the code after `await` is stuck into a `.then()` callback automatically (but not exactly like that).

Comment: @Pointy ... thank you, for the additional details.